# Swift Switch case on enum with Classes

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, associated-value

This is the first time I use this kind of enums, enum with associated value type, I need to make a `switch` statement depending on the object's type, I cannot managed to do it, this is the enum:

```
enum TypeEnum {
    case foo(FooClass)
    case doo(DooClass)
    case roo(RooClass)
}
```

My object has a variable of type `TypeEnum`, now I need to check which kind of object is in the enum:

```
if let anObject = object as? TypeEnum {

  switch anObject {
  case .foo(???):
     return true
    ...
    default:
      return false
    }

 }
```

I have no idea what to put instead of `???`. Xcode tells me to put something, but I just want to switch on `.foo`.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there something else being returned besides true and false?  If the answer is no then I would use `isKind(of:)` or `isMember(of:)`  as for your class right now, you need to fill in .foo with the instance of class you want to use, which is not what you probably want

Comment: [Swift Language Guide: Enumerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) Please read the the *Associated Values* section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `let` to capture the *[associated values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148)* for that:

```
switch anObject {
case .foo(let fooObj):
    ...
}
```

or nothing at *all* if you just don't care about them:

```
switch anObject {
case .foo:
    ...
}
```

Please be sure to check [the Swift Programming Language book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) for further details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the underscore to indicate that you aren't interested in the associated type:

```
case .foo(_):
...
```